# compile OpenBUGS 64-bit

Tags: compiler-construction, 64-bit, oberon

I need to compile OpenBUGS on a 64-bit machine but its repository (http://sourceforge.net/projects/openbugs/develop) consists of a bunch of .ocf files. Where can I find a compiler **that works on Linux** to do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contact the OpenBugs develop team before, I asked them why use object Pascal; they told me that "it's a good language".

I am quite curious why they use a blackbox complier, which is not cross-platform, for developing OpenBUGS.

May be [jags](http://www-fis.iarc.fr/~martyn/software/jags/) can be a much better choice for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's Object Pascal... check out the [developer manual for OpenBUGS](http://www.openbugs.info/Manuals/Developer/Manual.html)

Comment: Component Pascal is certainly not Object Pascal. It is a much later [Wirthian] design, distant relative to original pascal (Pascal -> Modula -> Modula 2 -> Oberon -> Oberon-2 -> Component Pascal). Object Pascal was Borlands bastardization of Pascal, a successful try to not take into account any progress Wirth & Co. did in the meantime.

Comment: @MiloslavRaus Back in 2010 it was using Object Pascal, in 5 years that may have changed. Even the URL has changed. Object Pascal was created in Apple (in collaboration with Wirth), not at Borland. Delphi was Borland's version of Object Pascal which was really just Turbo Pascal with Objects originally. Many OSS compilers, wishing to be compatible with Delphi, unable to use the name for copyright reasons, used the Object Pascal moniker so I can see how you'd find yourself confused.